# AND (&) disjunction in Parse IOS SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, parse-platform

I've been going over Parse's API for custom/relational queries, and was not able to find an example of creating a query that simulates that of an AND disjunction. For example, I would like to find an object whose "first" and "last" columns match values "John" and "Doe" respectively. The orQuery that exists in the PARSE API is a method simulates the OR conjunction (at least to my knowledge), so it's not what I need.

Any ideas on how to achieve this functionality (example would be great)?

Thanks

Comment: "OR conjunction" is called "disjunction" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably missed this somewhere in the documentation, but the answer is actually quite simple - just add multiple "equalTo" methods to your query:

```
[query whereKey:@"position" equalTo:@"forward"];
[query whereKey:@"team" equalTo:@"Sonics"];
```

This will give you an AND query that look for rows where both the position column is forward and the team column is Sonics.